# cannot use .bind() to bind hover

Tags: jquery

I experimenting with jQuery. As I was trying I found out that I can't use hover event with .bind. And I don't know what is wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.some-class').bind({
  hover: function(e) {
  // Hover event handler
   alert("hover");
  },
  click: function(e) {
  // Click event handler
   alert("click");
  },
  blur: function(e) {
  // Blur event handler
  }
 });
});
```

What is surprising (at least to me) is that hover is not working. The others "click" and "blur" are working fine.

Also the following works without any problems.

```
$(".some-class").hover(function(){
     // stuff
})
```

Maybe I can use the above code. But not knowing why is a big nuisance. So any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events (which [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) uses) directly when binding with an object like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.some-class').bind({
  mouseenter: function(e) {
  // Hover event handler
   alert("hover");
  },
  mouseleave: function(e) {
  // Hover event handler
   alert("hover");
  },
  click: function(e) {
  // Click event handler
   alert("click");
  },
  blur: function(e) {
  // Blur event handler
  }
 });
});
```

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)  [is defined specially here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/event.js#L981) in the jQuery event code...it simply isn't supported like other events in places like [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), since it's not an event, it's just a function to help you bind the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Answer (score 3):

Not much of a why, but it is simply not in the spec. Check the doc - hover is not listed in the bindable events.

http://api.jquery.com/bind/