# Binding hover & focus in jquery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery, bind

I have built a menu system with dropdowns which triggers on hover or focus and uses bind to capture either event:

```
$("#navi ul li a").not("#navi ul li ul li a").bind("hover focus", function() { hello });
```

The function ran perfectly using JQuery version 1.7, but since updating to 1.9.1 the bind seems to be failing. I tested this by removing the bind & running the function on hover only:

```
$("#navi ul li a").not("#navi ul li ul li a").hover(function() { hello });
```

This worked fine.

Where am i going wrong with the bind?

Comment: `#navi ul > li > a` would be a better selector and saves you the `not` bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot use .bind() to bind hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111194/cannot-use-bind-to-bind-hover)

Comment: Oops - pretty much the same issue, missed that one. Using mouseenter instead of hover resolved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFregoli - I tried that selector, but the function does fire on mouseeenter of 2nd level items

Comment: @user2352171 oh, right, maybe `#navi > ul > li > a`?

Comment: Ah yes - I see it is direct descendant selector. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#navi ul li a").not("#navi ul li ul li a").on("hover focus", function() { hello });
```