# Popup a window on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to show you a website [www.skinnyties.com.](http://skinnyties.com/)
I would like to ask that whenever you hover the mouse on collection/color etc the naviagation. then you can see that a new window pops up. 
I would like to ask how can i create such window on my own page.?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about javascript? Looks like you didn't even tried something...

Comment: FYI - Rollover pop ups = frowned upon. Unless you are talking about a "lightbox" "popup"?

Comment: You should probably looks at a few tutorials and try something.

Comment: I would like to see your code??

Comment: Look for tutorials on drop-down navigation patterns. For what they are doing, you just need a simple :hover {display:block;} on a child element of the navigation item.

Comment: And just what exactly is wrong with the implementation that SO uses when you hover over a tag - for instance, the `javascript` or `html` or `css` tags that this question possesses? The browser's debugger/element browser is your friend. :)

Comment: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-modern-css3-hover-effects

Comment: Check out tutorials and come back man. Your question is too generic and has a 1000 permutations and combinations. So be sure of what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use javascript for this -- for what you are asking for you just need CSS.

Look through these tutorials. They explain exactly how to accomplish what you want in a basic way.

http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

http://designmodo.com/css3-dropdown-menu/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the mouseenter and mouseleave events (which .hover() uses) directly when binding with an object like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.some-class').bind({
  mouseenter: function(e) {
  // Hover event handler
   alert("hover");
  },
  mouseleave: function(e) {
  // Hover event handler
   alert("hover");
  },
  click: function(e) {
  // Click event handler
   alert("click");
  },
  blur: function(e) {
  // Blur event handler
  }
 });
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6R7t/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111194/cannot-use-bind-to-bind-hover)

Comment: This is my code :
<div id="nav-container">
      <div id="nav-header">
    
    <h1 id="logo">
    <a href="http://skinnyties.com/"></a>
    </h1>
    
    <ol class="order-list"> 
     <li class="li-list">
             <a href="#">Collection</a>                              <a href="#">Color</a> 
              <a href="#">Width</a>
       <a href="#">Fabric</a>
       <a href="#">Pattern</a>
     </li>
    </ol>
    
     
   </div> 
  </div>

Answer (score 1):

I've a solution. Please refers http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/JaYmn/1/

Here is the code.

```
$(document).delegate('.option','mouseenter',function(){
$('.option-container').addClass('hidden');
$(this).next('.option-container').removeClass('hidden');
});

$(document).delegate('.option-container','mouseleave',function(){
$(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a div set its position to absolute move it where you want it and set display to none.

Then use the mouseover event of your navigation link and set the display to block with javascript.

Comment: This is my code :
<div id="nav-container">
      <div id="nav-header">
    
    <h1 id="logo">
    <a href="http://skinnyties.com/"></a>
    </h1>
    
    <ol class="order-list"> 
     <li class="li-list">
             <a href="#">Collection</a>                              <a href="#">Color</a> 
              <a href="#">Width</a>
       <a href="#">Fabric</a>
       <a href="#">Pattern</a>
     </li>
    </ol>
    
     
   </div> 
  </div>