# Upgrading jQuery breaks pop-out submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code to display a menu with pop-out submenus when each menu item is hovered over.

jQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var hoverAttributes = {
                speed: 10,
                delay: 100
        };
        $("#nav-home").bind("hover", hoverAttributes, function(){
            $("#subnav").children().hide();
            $("#sub-home").show();
        });
        $("#nav-library").bind("hover", hoverAttributes, function(){
            $("#subnav").children().hide();
            $("#sub-library").show();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="nav">
        <table align="right">
            <tr>
                <td id="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="../home" id="nav-home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../library" id="nav-library">Library</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="subnav">
                    <ul id="sub-home">
                        <li><a href="../home/forum.jsp">Forums</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../home/news.jsp">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../home/about.jsp">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="sub-library">
                        <li><a href="../library/resources.jsp">Resources</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../library/glossary.jsp">Glossary</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../library/references.jsp">References</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

This code works using jquery-1.6.1.min.js, but when I upgrade to jquery-1.12.4.min.js, the pop-out functionality breaks.  On page load, the first menu item (Home) has its submenu already expanded.  Mousing over it or other menu items causes no change in what's displayed.

I've found that the `bind()` action was deprecated in jQuery 3.0, but it should still work for 1.12.4, shouldn't it?  I can't find any record of `children()`, `hide()` or `show()` being deprecated.

For context, I know very little about jQuery and JavaScript.  This came up because I have to fix someone else's code.

Comment: I don't think [bind works with hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111194/cannot-use-bind-to-bind-hover)

Comment: @HMR You're correct, I just found that it does not as of 1.9 ([release notes](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#quot-hover-quot-pseudo-event)).  As a minimum fix, replacing "hover" with "mouseenter" works, but I'm going to try out user3585143 's more sophisticated solution, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing .bind to `$(".selector").on("mouseover", function () {..});`

Comment: This works, thanks!  The original usage of "hover" was deprecated at jQuery 1.9, with "mouseover" being the best replacement.  Upgrading `bind()` to `on()` is a bonus.